# PhoneGap, application has stopped

Tags: cordova

I'm getting the dreaded application has stopped error, as I see many others have.  I am having no luck with it.  I simply do not know where to begin I guess.  here is my Manifest.  What else is needed to assist with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="5">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="Multiply" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest> 
E/AndroidRuntime(24115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply/org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply.Multiply}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply.Multiply
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2012)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply.Multiply
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2003)
E/AndroidRuntime(24115):    ... 11 more
D/PowerManagerService(  715): releaseDVFSLockLocked : remain DVFS_MIN_LIMIT : next : 102600
```

Comment: What do you see in "adb logcat"?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of things just constantly fly by.  Nothing relevant though.  Is there a way to control what its looking at?

Comment: I think I found what is relevant... editing.

Comment: Thanks for the logcat tip.  This is now solved. I had to go back to the Manifest general attributes and select the proper package name. Take care!  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not deploy all jar files / classes to the device:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.danjoseph.me.apps.multiply.Multiply
```